# "You have until X to do Y" — is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis

I have a question regarding the following sentence:

> You have **until** June 6th to go there.

Is it grammatically incorrect?

Consider the following:

*You* is the subject, *have* is the verb, *until June 6th* and *to go there* are both adverbs. Does this make *have* not have an object?

Comment: _until June 6th_ is not an adverb, it is a prepositional phrase (PP). _to go there_ is not an adverb, it does not modify the preceding clause.

Comment: preposition + noun = adverb phrase right?

Comment: A prepositional phrase (PP = preposition + noun phrase) that plays the role of an adverb may be called an "adverbial (phrase)" not "adverb". Adverbial phrases are non-obligatory elements that modify the verb/clause. It seems to me that this sense of "have" **requires** a second argument (such as "until June 6th"), so it's not an adverbial phrase but an obligatory element.

Comment: Can until June 6th be an object if it isn't a noun?  I really don't understand this. What's the logical explanation?

Comment: Various structures can act as [core arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)), so long as they are of the structure required/allowed by the particular verb.

Comment: Perhaps it will help to consider the parallel expressions "You have until June 6th" and "You have three days". Either may replace or explain the other: "You have until June 6th–three days" or "You have three days–until June 6th."

Comment: I found this information on the web. The structure is discussed in the following article. Makoto Sumiyoshi (2011). "Non-compositionality, syntactic irregularity and phraseology: An analysis of "*have until* X *to* V"" Joanna, S. (ed.) *Research of Phraseology in Europe and Asia: Focal Issues on Phraseological Studies (Intercontinental Dialogue on Phraseology, Vol. 1)* pp.153-175. University of Bialystok Publishing House. Bialystok: Poland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an English native (American), this looks and feels correct to me.

"You have until the 20th to complete your homework."

"You have until tomorrow to pay back what you owe."

"You have until morning to finish your paper."

"You have until the end of the month to catch up with your assignments."

Comment: yes! thats what i thought, but is there an explanation for this? gramatically speaking

Comment: Ah, right. If an adverb modifies a verb, then **have** in this case is the modified verb. And adverb or adverbial phrase does not replace the verb itself, but merely modifies it.

Comment: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm

Comment: More insights may be found here as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause

Comment: oooh so thats why it doesnt need the object, okay thank you.